# LuxPro PSP600 thermostat replacement

Tags: hvac

My HVAC unit has an old LuxPro PSP600 thermostat, which started to fail. It seems the old model is no longer available anywhwere. What alternative is compatible with its wiring/wallplate? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is a typical 24V thermostat, with all the usual mostly color-coded wires. You should be able to swap for any 24V thermostat, either a standard one or a "smart" one with WiFi, etc. such as Nest.

If you want to make 100% sure, open up the thermostat by removing it from the wall base panel and take a picture of the wires/screw terminals. That will tell you what wires are currently connected. If there are any wires that are not currently connected, make sure to get a picture of those too. Then we can compare the functions of those wires, based on [the manual](https://pro.luxproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PSP600_NL_ENG_Manual.pdf) to see if you have everything needed for a particular new thermostat.

Many "smart" (particularly WiFi-enabled) thermostats require a "C" wire in order to get 24V AC power all the time, as battery power is not practical. However, there are many modern thermostats without internet connectivity that do not require the "C" wire.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LuxPro PSP600 thermostat` was battery operated.

All modern thermostat require 24 V AC supplied from the main control board transformer.

First find out if you do have 24 V AC wires using a multimeter tool.

Many people do not have the 24 V- Common wire so check if you have it, if not we have to deal with that.

While at it, please report how many wires you have (2 for 24 Volt) and one each for heating, cooling, Fan ?

Color code wires are not reliable, therefore use the Letters.

After that any modern thermostat will work.

Your current wiring might look like this.

[image: wire]

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had to do this and purchased a smart Honeywell RTH9585WF thermometer.  This kit comes with a "C" wire, just an about two inches long you'll use to hop over from your G wire to your cooling system.  Which doesn't make much sense reading that.  But the directions are simple just remember to go by the letters not the color, there will also be a supplied sticker kit to label.  Take a before photo of before you take the plate off so you can see what terminals they were in.  I guess long story short I just did this a week ago replaced a battery powered thermo for that Honeywell and the directions were pretty simple after reading them a couple times, just go step by step.

Comment: I removed the chatty introduction and the suggestion of where to buy and rebate info as that's time sensitive and won't be of any use to anyone else in less than a month. It's likely your answer will live on here for many years, so that kind of "shopping advice" is considered off topic.